# How to stop Google Colab from disconnecting?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am training a model on Google Colab. It keeps disconnecting and I have to restart it again. How do I stop it?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your internet connection is stable. Stop using all apps, devices, and all virtual reality connections.